# Multiple statuses on a page?

Tags: channel-entries, status

I currently have a block of code that looks like

And the problem I'm trying to resolve is that I have a section on a different page using all of these statuses in their own divs to create a sort of Editor's Choice area.  shown here:

```
THE FEATURED STATUS
{exp:channel:entries channel="news|blog|misc" limit="1" dynamic="no" status="Featured"}
  <div class="featured img">
    an image
  </div>
  <div class="featured text">
    text that links to article view template
      <div><a class="color-red lg featured read-more" href="{site_url}{channel_short_name}/view/{url_title}">Full Article&hellip;</a>
      </div>
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}  

EDCHOICE STATUS
{exp:channel:entries channel="news|blog|misc" limit="1" dynamic="no" status="EdChoice"}
  <div class="EdChoice1 img">
    an image
  </div>
  <div class="EdChoice1 text">
    text that links to article view template
      <div><a class="color-red lg featured read-more" href="{site_url}{channel_short_name}/view/{url_title}">Full Article&hellip;</a>
      </div>
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries} 

EDCHOICE STATUS
{exp:channel:entries channel="news|blog|misc" limit="1" dynamic="no" status="EdChoice"}
  <div class="EdChoice2 img">
    an image
  </div>
  <div class="EdChoice2 text">
    text that links to article view template
      <div><a class="color-red lg featured read-more" href="{site_url}{channel_short_name}/view/{url_title}">Full Article&hellip;</a>
      </div>
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And those populate perfectly fine.  And the articles pulled with EdChoice status work when clicked on basically pulling up their respective channels view template and displaying the article.  HOWEVER, anything with the status of Featured shows and goes to the correct url, but does not display and obviously redirects to my 404 page.  Here is a block of what's in my view template, of which all the articles (EdChoice, Featured, Open, or otherwise) are pulling:

```
 {exp:channel:entries site="{site_short_name}" channel="news|blog|misc" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" dynamic="no" status="Open|Featured|EdChoice" require_entry="yes"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if} 
    <h1><span itemprop="name">{title}</span></h1>
            etc etc 
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

And when I changed THE FEATURED STATUS block status to status="EdChoice" the view page works fine.  I'm not sure what's going on here.  Has anyone encountered this before? Or know what I'm doing wrong as I am new to using multiple statuses

Comment: Have you checked that you have a status called "Featured" (with a capital F) and it's correctly spelt?

Comment: Yep, has a capital F and everything.. hahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove everything from your template and just add this:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="news|blog|misc" status="not closed"}
    {title} 
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

If this works, start adding code back in piece by piece until things break.

Comment: I removed everything and worked my way up on a new template group, everything works fine-but, when I pull that exact code into other templates is when it fails.  There are some snippets etc on those pages that I'm going to take a look at -also there is a user-friendly version of control panel built to mirror what's going on channel entry wise with EE's default control panel using safecracker also feeding and populating into a holding ground for all of the articles which are then shipped out in snippets and custom field groups, so I'll look a little deeper to see what's going on there...

Answer (score 1):

The `exp:channel:entries` tag by default only looks for [**status="open"**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#status) entries.

Might be best to use `status="not closed`" in your setup. This will show all entries except those using the "closed" status.

Comment: I have tried using status="not closed" with no success already. swapping out status="Open|Featured|EdChoice" for status="not closed"

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting `url_title="{segment_3}"` and `dynamic="no"` try removing the `require_entry="yes"` parameter from your `exp:channel:entries` tag.

OR

Remove `url_title="{segment_3}"` and `dynamic="no"`, and leave the `require_entry="yes"` parameter.

Comment: {exp:channel:entries site="{site_short_name}" channel="news"  limit="1" dynamic="no" status="Open|Featured|EdChoice"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if} 
    <h1><span itemprop="name">{title}</span></h1>
            etc etc 
 {/exp:channel:entries} 

 {exp:channel:entries site="{site_short_name}" channel="news"  limit="1" dynamic="no" status="not closed"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if} 
    <h1><span itemprop="name">{title}</span></h1>
            etc etc 
 {/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: tried both of these and still no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `site="{site_short_name}"` from your tag. This parameter isn't present on your working code.

Comment: Hmmm.. so I tried that and I swear it was going to work when I hit update finished and refreshed.. but it didn't.  OH my?

Comment: The current 2 code options I've tried. `{exp:channel:entries channel="news"  limit="1" dynamic="no" status="Open|Featured|EdChoice"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if} 
    <h1><span itemprop="name">{title}</span></h1>
            etc etc 
 {/exp:channel:entries} 

 {exp:channel:entries channel="news"  limit="1" dynamic="no" status="not closed"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if} 
    <h1><span itemprop="name">{title}</span></h1>
            etc etc 
 {/exp:channel:entries}`